# Why do I only get one marker from my location array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I know the problem but can’t find the solution.

I want to get all markers in my `location` array.

Here is my code:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

var locations = new Array();
var lati = "";
var longi = "";
var cityfrom = "";

posts.forEach((item, index) => {
  lati = item.acf.maps.lat;
  longi = item.acf.maps.lng;
  cityfrom = item.title.rendered;
});
locations = [
  {
    lat: lati,
    lng: longi,
    city: cityfrom
  },
];
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/hobboh/pen/bGGgNbJ)

Answer (score 1):

You only assign the last values of `lati`, `longi`, and `cityfrom` to a single item in the array, and easier option would be to use `Array.map()` to create the array:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

const locations = posts.map((item, index) => ({
  lati: item.acf.maps.lat,
  longi: item.acf.maps.lng,
  cityfrom: item.title.rendered,
}));
```